# Inicialización estructura en C con memoria dinamica

Tags: c, manejo-de-memoria

Tengo estas dos estructuras:

```
typedef struct{
      char* username;
      char* name;
      char* mail;
}tPlayer

typedef struct{
      char* name;
      tPlayer* owner;
}tTeam;
```

tTeam es una estructura que ya me viene dada, se supone que tengo que guardar el nombre y la referencia (puntero) a tPlayer.
Estoy tratando de inicializar una estructura tTeam pero por algún motivo no lo hace, :

```
tError team_init(tTeam* object, const char* name, tPlayer* owner) {

    // Verify pre conditions
    assert(object != NULL);
    assert(name != NULL);
    assert(owner->name != NULL);
    assert(owner->username != NULL);
    assert(owner->mail != NULL);

    object->name = (char*) malloc((strlen(name) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    object->owner->username = (char*) malloc((strlen(owner->username) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    object->owner->name = (char*) malloc((strlen(owner->name) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    object->owner->mail = (char*) malloc((strlen(owner->mail) + 1) * sizeof(char));

    if(object->name == NULL || object->owner->username == NULL || object->owner->name == NULL || object->owner->mail == NULL) {

        return ERR_MEMORY_ERROR;
    }

    strcpy(object->name, name);
    strcpy(object->owner->username, owner->username);
    strcpy(object->owner->name, owner->name);
    strcpy(object->owner->mail, owner->mail);

    return OK;  
}
```

Alguna idea de donde esta fallando?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿No te falta reservar espacio para `object->owner`?

Comment: Buenas, he probado  con object->owner = malloc * sizeof(owner); pero no funciona.

Comment: Supongo que querrás decir `malloc(1*sizeof(owner))` pero aún así está mal, puesto que `sizeof(owner)` te da el tamaño de la variable `owner`, que es un puntero, por lo que obtienes el tamaño de un puntero (muy diferente de lo que quieres: el tamaño del objeto al que apunta). Debes usar `object->owner = malloc(sizeof(tPlayer))`

Comment: Estoy empezando en C y ando un poco perdido, entiendo que si hago object->owner = malloc(sizeof(tPlayer)) ya no hace falta hacer object->owner->username = (char*) malloc((strlen(owner->username) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    object->owner->name = (char*) malloc((strlen(owner->name) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    object->owner->mail = (char*) malloc((strlen(owner->mail) + 1) * sizeof(char)); no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puesto que en un comentario el usuario reconoce que anda un poco perdido (lo cual no era evidente viendo que el código es profuso en punteros, que no son material para principiantes), intentaré aclarar un poco más la respuesta que di en un comentario.

Cuando en C declaras un puntero, en principio éste no apunta a "ninguna parte" (o siendo más exactos, apunta a un lugar aleatorio de la memoria). Esto en general es peligroso si intentas acceder (y sobre todo modificar) lo que hay allí, pues no sabes qué dirección será. Si es una dirección protegida por el operativo, éste terminará tu programa con un error (en linux un *segfault*). Pero si no era protegida, estarás modificando parte de la memoria del proceso, con consecuencias imprevisibles.

Por tanto siempre hay que hacer que un puntero apunte a algún lugar válido antes de poder usarlo. La función `malloc()` sirve para hacer que el puntero apunte a una zona "segura", reservada en ese momento de una zona llamada "el montón" (*heap*). Tienes que especificar el tamaño en bytes que necesitas, y asegurarte de no usar más, pues invadirías otras zonas del montón. También debes recordar liberar esa memoria (`free()`) cuando ya no la necesites, para que así pueda ser asignada de nuevo cuando uses otro `malloc()`. No hacerlo implica que tu programa irá consumiendo cada vez más memoria de forma innecesaria mientras esté en ejecución (*memory leak*).

Yendo ya a tu código. No sólo tienes punteros, sino que éstos apuntan a estructuras cuyos campos son a su vez punteros a otras estructuras (y dentro de éstas, hay más punteros, en este caso a cadenas).

```
typedef struct{
      char* username;
      char* name;
      char* mail;
}tPlayer

typedef struct{
      char* name;
      tPlayer* owner;
}tTeam;
```

Cuando recibes un puntero a `tTeam`  y quieres inicializar esa estructura, ya que ésta tiene dentro dos punteros (`name` y `owner`), ambos deben ser inicializados. A su vez, `owner` apunta a otra estructura que contiene otros tres punteros, también a inicializar.

Tu código usa esta expresión:

```
object->owner->username = malloc(...);
```

sin haber creado antes memoria para el campo `owner`. Por tanto tenemos un puntero `object` que apunta a una zona de memoria (que suponemos bien inicializada por quien haya llamado a nuestra función), dentro de la cual hay otro puntero ( `owner`) que apunta a no se sabe dónde. En esa zona aleatoria a la que apunta, asumimos que hay una estructura con un campo `username` cuyo valor cambiamos. Por tanto estaremos escribiendo algo (el valor retornado por `malloc()`) en una dirección de memoria desconocida, con los problemas que ello supone antes explicados.

El tema se resuelve reservando memoria para `owner` antes de intentar acceder a sus campos. Pero a `malloc()` hay que decirle cuántos bytes necesitamos. Lo que pretendemos guardar en la dirección a que apunta `owner` es una estructura de tipo `tPlayer` ¿cuántos bytes ocupa esta estructura? Por suerte no necesitamos conocer la respuesta ya que podemos usar el operador `sizeof()` para obtenerla. A este operador se le pasa el nombre de un tipo y nos devuelve cuántos bytes ocupa una variable de ese tipo.  Por tanto:

```
object->owner = malloc(sizeof(tPlayer));
```

También se le puede pasar el nombre de una variable, y entonces nos dirá cuántos bytes ocupa la variable. Pero cuidado, si le pasas una variable de tipo puntero te diría cuántos bytes ocupa un puntero, lo cual no suele ser lo que necesitas (todos los punteros ocupan lo mismo, independientemente del dato a que apunten, ya que todos los punteros almacenan únicamente una dirección de memoria que es un número de tamaño fijo).

Naturalmente la línea anterior sólo reserva la memoria que necesita la estructura `tPlayer`. Esta estructura contiene tres punteros (`username`, `name`, y `mail`), por lo que en el fondo hemos reservado sitio para guardar esos tres punteros, pero **no** para los datos a los que éstos apunten. Aún serían necesarios los `malloc()` para esos punteros.

Para simplificar, puedes cambiar los `malloc()` usados para apuntar a cadenas (que después copias con `strcpy()`) por una llamada a `strdup()`. Esta función *duplica*  en el *heap* la cadena que recibe como parámetro, para lo cual internamente llama a `malloc()` para reservar espacio, llama a `strcpy()` para copiarla, y te devuelve finalmente el puntero a la cadena copiada en el *heap*. Ya que internamente usó `malloc()`, debes recordar hacer `free()` cuando ya no lo necesites.

Con esto tu código quedaría (gestión de errores aparte):

```
object->name = strdup(name);
object->owner = malloc(sizeof(tPlayer));
object->owner->username = strdup(owner->username);
object->owner->name = strdup(owner->name);
object->owner->mail = strdup(owner->email);
```

Cuando quieras liberar la memoria que has reservado, debes hacerlo en orden inverso. Es decir, primero los punteros más internos, y después los más externos:

```
free(object->owner->username);
free(object->owner->name);
free(object->owner->email);
free(object->owner);
free(object->name);
```

Si liberases antes `object->owner`, perderías ya el acceso a sus punteros internos `object->owner->username`, etc. y no podrían ser liberados. Tendrías un caso típico de *memory leak*.

Answer (score 0):

Estamos con el mismo ejercicio, soy compañero tuyo y estoy como tú.

Te comento una respuesta de la consultora, aunque no me ha funcionado igualmente (es sin usar strsdup pues no lo han comentado.

En principio no hace falta  la reserva de memoria

```
object->owner = malloc(sizeof(tPlayer));
```

Bastaría con la reserva

```
object->name = (char*) malloc((strlen(name) + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

pues owner apunta a un struct que ya tiene la reserva de memoria hecha.
Para asignar los valores debería bastar con

```
strcpy(object->name, name);
object->owner = owner;
```

Pero no me pasa el test igualmente.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
tError team_init(tTeam* object, const char* name, tPlayer* owner) {

  // Verify pre conditions

  assert(object!=NULL);
  assert(name!=NULL);
  assert(owner!=NULL);


  // Allocate the memory for all the fields, using the length of the provided text plus 1 space for the "end of string" char '\0'. 
  //To allocate memory we use the malloc command.

  object->name = (char*) malloc((strlen(name) + 1) * sizeof(char));
  //object->owner = (tPlayer*) malloc(sizeof(tPlayer)); //No és necesari

  // Check that memory has been allocated for all fields. Pointer must be different from NULL.

    if(object->name == NULL || object->owner == NULL) {

        // Some of the fields have a NULL value, what means that we found some problem allocating the memory

        return ERR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED;   
    }

  // Once the memory is allocated, copy the data. When the fields are strings, we need to use the string copy function strcpy. 

    strcpy(object->name, name);
    object->owner = owner; 

    return OK;
}
```

A ver si alguien sabe dónde puede estar el error

Comment: StackOveflow es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas, no sigue la mecánica de un foro donde se pueden mezclar cosas en un "hilo". En el apartado de respuestas sólo debería haber eso, respuestas, y no otras preguntas. Te pediría que abrieras una nueva pregunta y si quieres desde ella hagas referencia a esta otra (con un enlace mejor), y añadas las dudas adicionales que no hayan quedado resueltas aquí.

Comment: Por otro lado, dices que no te pasa una validación ¿no tienes más información? ¿No te da algún mensaje indicando qué es lo que no valida correctamente? ¿Dónde está la especificación completa de lo que se supone que ha de hacer?

Comment: Llevo poco por aquí y no sabía que solo eran respuestas sobre el mismo tema. He abierto otro hilo similar y lo he cerrado porque me han comentado que estaba este que no había encontrado. Puedo subir el código del test que realiza o abrir otro hilo y publicar los archivos, ando un poco perdido, disculpa.

Comment: No pasa nada, es normal esto al principio. Por eso los moderadores añadimos estos comentarios. Como dije, creo que lo correcto es abrir otro "hilo" (es decir, hacer una nueva pregunta) y aprovechar para completar en ella los detalles que faltan en ésta. De paso te comento que cuando pegues código, debes seleccionarlo y pulsar el botón `{}` de la barra de herramientas, para que salga correctamente formateado.

Comment: Gracias por las aclaraciones, abufalia. De hecho, me parece que has sido tú quién me ha comentado que estaba esta pregunta y por eso he eliminado la consulta que había hecho. Miraré de crear otro post y a ver si pongo la información adecuada y necesaria. Gracias